# Как запустить *.exe на удаленном кластере через эту консоль?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, администрирование, кластер

Мне нужно было протестировать свою программу на C# которая моделирует нечто на мощном компьютере. Я попросил доступ к университетскому кластеру и он был предоставлен с некими инструкциями + WinCSP + Putty. В инструкции сказано как компилить С\С++ файлы и полученное запускать, но не понятно как запускать exe файлы или что делать если у меня оконное приложение. Мог бы загуглить вот только консоль "inparcom" не гуглиться вообще. Что такое система imparcom? Как с помощью putty и wincsp запускать не только скомпилированные С\С++ файлы? Так же есть альтернативная форма управления через веб интерфейс (ACMS). У кого то есть подобный опыт?

Comment: А почему вы использовали команду help, а не Help, как раз меняли и другие команды?

Comment: В инструкции было написано с большой буквы, я это потом исправил. А так еще  сначала не разобрался с <count>, но потом понял.

Comment: Эммм... может я чё-то не знаю, но ты уверен, что на unix-like ОС у тебя получится запустить оконную прогу написанную на шарпе?

Comment: @donRumata это не так сложно как вы думаете - есть же Mono. Гораздо хуже тот факт, что там кластер, а случайная прога не умеет исполняться на кластере.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я в курсе и про моно и про неткор и про вайн. Тут вопрос в другом: на сколько пОлно реализованы все фичи в этих проектах, которые юзает конкретная прога. Типа винформс и т.д.

Comment: Вообще не проблема убрать лишнее или что то дописать, может даже найти либу для mpi. Но что будет на выходе написания на моно? тоже ехе? в таком случае у меня не получиться его использовать. Похоже что придется все переделывать на плюсах.

Answer (score 3):

Это mpi-кластер, причем, судя по всему, под Linux. Для него нужно писать специальные программы с использованием библиотек mpi. Компилировать их можно и на своём компьютере, но они должны линковаться с реализацией mpi, установленной на кластере, из-за чего проще компилировать сразу на месте.

Как там реализована работа с GPU - не известно, скорее всего используется OpenCL, т.к. доступен запуск как на CPU, так и на GPU. В любом случае, для доступа к контексту выполнения должны быть специальные библиотечные интерфейсы, совместимые с планировщиком, их можно поискать среди доступных пакетов.

Оконное приложение там вряд ли получится запустить, на кластера графическую подсистему обычно не ставят. Тем более не получится запустить exe - файл.